# how could an erlang port's port info change to undefined?

Tags: erlang, erlang-ports

I get a erlang server, and many clients use tcp to connect to the server.

After some minutes, use erlang:ports() and erlang:port_info(), I can find some port's port_info is undefined, and the port is closed.I can't find anyway to remove it from ports.

So why did it happen, and how could I remove these undefined port from erlang ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `erlang:port_info/1` function returns `undefined` if the port is not open.

You're calling that function on a port which you didn't open or that has been closed.

Please note that if the Erlang process which created the port (the *connected* process) terminates, the port will automatically close.

Comment: Thanks for reply.In my server,the port is close,and return undefined,but the process which create this port is still alive. Then I kill the process, but the port is still there, and return undefined.I use exit(normal) to kill the process, is it wrong? or when it throw error could cause something wrong?

Comment: And another question, will the port close automatically when the process is still alive?

Comment: You can explicitly close a port via erlang:port_close/1. Maybe you want to share some code?

Comment: My code is too long, could you give me your email?In fact,it seems like the link of tcp client process and the port was broken.I use process_info to get the tcp client process info ,most of them are normal,but some of them have no port's link there.

Comment: You can create a Gist: https://gist.github.com/. I'm not really willing to give you an answer about some code which can't be shared with the other users :)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/3181283,   all of the error process current_function is this.As you see,when the port close, then will call lib_tcp:do_lost(), and the port will be closed.Those error processes had not link to the port, but still waiting to receive something. the process_info just like this https://gist.github.com/3181305